# Upgrade MVC 2 to MVC 3 issues with views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to upgrade my existing ASP.net MVC 2 web application to MVC 3 so I can use the goodness that is the Razor Viewengine and other [said](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) improvements.

After using the converter to convert my app from mvc2 to mvc3 I'm having issues with my strongly typed views.  As an example here we have a view user control that is strongly typed to the class Profile

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Profile>" %>
```

During compilation I'm getting

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'folio' and no extension method 'folio' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

which corresponds to this line in my view
[image]

So it's like the views are no longer accepting a type.  This is happening w/ user controls as well as full on views.

I've checked both web.config and views/web.config and both seem to be referencing System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0

Any help would be appreciated!

See below for screen captures of web.configs

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly, make sure that you also update Views\Web.config it solved the problem for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in MVC 3 Preview 1, and will be addressed in the next release. In the interim, you can rearrange your pages so that the <%@ Control %> directive is the last one in the file and that should the issue for you.

Comment: So this seems like it's making it a non usable preview.  It also appears as if perhaps for the same reason intellisense is no longer intact in the view.

Comment: @Phil, the preview should still be usable for your scenario with the workaround that Brad suggested. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: So moving it to the bottom did fix some of my pages but others were having buffer cannot be null exceptions being thrown in System.IO.MemoryStream ..... case in point it's not ready for even development IMHO.  I have over a hundred views and controls and that would be a nightmare to move the directive line to the bottom even if it was 100% reliable

Comment: Yes, this was fixed for Beta.

Answer (score 5):

I simply replaced the web.config in my 'Views' folder (with one from a newly created mvc3 project) as the migration suggested and it worked for me. I wasn't prepared to move all the declarations to the bottom as my project was just too big.

Hope it helps although this is probably too late for you. Maybe it helps others...

Answer (score 4):

On the off chance try changing your `bindingRedirect` to

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: This didn't help but I agree that a brand new mvc 3 project does use this instead of the double dependentAssembly entries for 1.0 to 2.0 and 2.0 to 3.0

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would have never known it was a bug...it was the only real difference between my config and yours that might have been pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and after pulling my hair out a bit, found and followed Wiaan's solution.  Worked perfectly, and the site is back up.

Funny enough *not* making this change on our dev boxes did not break our site - it was only when we moved it to a staging server that it surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is based on MVC4 or using Framwork 4 already, create mvc4 empty project. And then replace web.config in views folder. It works immediately. Thanks, Wianne. Since I have kind of old app that used aspx rather than razor. After I upgraded Framework 3 to 4, I got this error.